# Titanic dataset in R

Tags: r

I am trying to work in a problem for the "Titanic" dataset in R.

In this data, the last column gives the frequency of observations ('freq' column).
For example- the third row says that frequency = 35, which means that this particular row will be repeated 35 times.

I am therefore coding a new data frame in which all the rows which have a frequency > 0 are printed those many times (row number 3 is appended in the new data frame, 35 times).

The total number of rows in the new data frame = 2201, which is the sum of all values in frequency column.

I have used a character vector of length 2201 to store all the values for the first column "Class" in which I am appending the values.

I have written the following code-

```
data(Titanic)
# View(Titanic)

# create a data frame out of 'Titanic' data frame-
T <- as.data.frame(Titanic, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# cat("Total # of observations - ", sum(T$Freq))    # O/P = 2201
n <- sum(T$Freq)


# full_titanic <- data.frame(Class = character(n), Sex = character(n), Age = character(n), Survived = character(n), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

full_Class <- character(n)  # create an array of 2201 character objects

for(i in 1:nrow(T))
{
    if(T$Freq[i] > 0)
    {
        cnt = T$Freq[i]
        # repeating_val <- T$Class[i]
        j <- 0

        while(j < cnt)
        {
            # full_Class[i] <- repeating_val
            full_Class[i + j] <- T$Class[i]
            # cat("T$Class[", i, "] = ", T$Class[i], "\n")
            # cat("Repeating for i = ", i, "\n")
            j <- j + 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        full_Class[i] <- T$Class[i]
    }

    # cat("i = ", i, "\n")
}
```

However, this code is leaving a lot of blanks in the character vector 'full_Class' when I print it.

I am able to see the discrepancy as-

```
table(full_Class) # shows the sum of all classes = 1520

sum(T$Freq[T$Class == "1st"]) # equals 325

sum(T$Freq[T$Class == "2nd"]) # equals 285

sum(T$Freq[T$Class == "3rd"]) # equals 706

sum(T$Freq[T$Class == "Crew"]) # equals 885

(325 - 67) + (285 - 11) + (706 - 63) + (885 - 540) # equalss 1520
```

What's going wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: suppose data is in `d1` and rows with `Freq == 0` are removed: `d1[rep(1:nrow(d1), d1$Freq), ]`

Comment: removing data with rows with `Freq == 0` will give me a dataset where I am missing those rows. I want to get a new dataset containing all the data.

Comment: how do you repeat something 0 times?

Comment: you don't repeat it, you just include it. There are 8 such rows which are - 1  2  4  5  6  8 20 24 (for which 'Freq == 0')

Comment: Then I suggest you edit this phrase in your question: __"I am therefore coding a new data frame in which all the rows which have a frequency > 0 are printed those many times (row number 3 is appended in the new data frame, 35 times)."__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
T1<-T[T$Freq==0,] # data with zero frequency
T2<-T[rep(row.names(T),T$Freq),] #data with nonzero frequency
T3<-rbind(T1,T2) #full data 
rownames(T3) <- 1:nrow(T3) #reset row index of full data
```

The output

`> head(T3,20)
   Class    Sex   Age Survived Freq
1    1st   Male Child       No    0
2    2nd   Male Child       No    0
3   Crew   Male Child       No    0
4    1st Female Child       No    0
5    2nd Female Child       No    0
6   Crew Female Child       No    0
7   Crew   Male Child      Yes    0
8   Crew Female Child      Yes    0
9    3rd   Male Child       No   35
10   3rd   Male Child       No   35
11   3rd   Male Child       No   35
12   3rd   Male Child       No   35
13   3rd   Male Child       No   35
14   3rd   Male Child       No   35
15   3rd   Male Child       No   35
16   3rd   Male Child       No   35
17   3rd   Male Child       No   35
18   3rd   Male Child       No   35
19   3rd   Male Child       No   35
20   3rd   Male Child       No   35`

Comment: Just adding a change => `actual_titanic <- as.data.frame(T3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`